# How to map a list of object to a DataTable using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, datatable, automapper

This is my current code.

```
public class IncidentMapDatatableProfile : Profile
{
    public IncidentMapDatatableProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<FlattenedIncident, DataRow>();
    }
}

public static class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static MapperConfiguration ConfigureMappings()
    {
        return new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {     
            cfg.AddProfile<IncidentMapDatatableProfile>();
        });
    }
}
```

But when I run this third line below, I got this error:

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: 'Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.'

```
var mapperConfig = AutoMapperConfig.ConfigureMappings();
IMapper mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();

var incidentsDatatable = mapper.Map<DataTable>(flattenedIncidents);
```

Looks like it could be due to the object mapping to a `DataRow`, will it be able to map to a `DataTable` later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that AutoMapper provides the feature to map the source to the destination either `DataTable` or `DataRow` type.

You should implement the function to convert the `List<T>` to `DataTable`. If you are able to implement it, I don't think there is a need to use AutoMapper in this case.

In summary, the reflection is needed to obtain the properties from the object and add the property name and value into the DataRow.

```cs
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
        where T : class, new()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        
        if (source == null || !source.Any())
            return dt;
        
        PropertyInfo[] propInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        
        foreach (var propInfo in propInfos)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(propInfo.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propInfo.PropertyType) ?? propInfo.PropertyType);  
        }
        
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            
            foreach (var propInfo in propInfos)
            {
                row[propInfo.Name] = propInfo.GetValue(item);   
            }
            
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        
        return dt;
    }
}
```

If you are still looking for an AutoMapper solution, you need to implement the [Custom Type Resolver](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html).

DataTable Converter:

```cs
public class ToDataTableConverter<T> : ITypeConverter<List<T>, DataTable>
    where T : class, new()
{
    public DataTable Convert(List<T> source, DataTable destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {       
        return source.ToDataTable();
    }
}
```

Mapping rules:

```cs
CreateMap<List<FlattenedIncident>, DataTable>()
            .ConvertUsing(new ToDataTableConverter<FlattenedIncident>());
```

Caller:

```cs
var incidentsDatatable = mapper.Map<DataTable>(flattenedIncidents);

// Or
//var incidentsDatatable = flattenedIncidents.ToDataTable();
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ra4bjD)

Comment: But you can map from an object to a dictionary and _then_ from the dictionary to `DataRow`.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, oh, maybe I need some time to test and provide the solution according to your feedback. Thanks.